# Transfering contact information from one phone to another using SIM card

Tags: lg

I have a LG Optimus L70 phone that will no longer turn on. I have a new LG K7 phone. How can I transfer my contact information to the new phone using the SIM card. Or is there any other way that I can get my contact information and pictures off of my old phone and put in to my new phone

Comment: How do you want to "transfer" something from dead phone? If the contacts are on the SIM card already - just insert it to the new phone.

Comment: AD apparently you did not understand my question. I was inquiring as to whether this was possible and how to do it. On top of this the sims card for my old phone is to big to be placed in my new phone. I detected just a little bit of sarcasm in your comment. And between me and you I don't need that from you or anyone else.

Comment: Wrong detection :) Anyway I don't see any option how to do this or to transfer *anything* from something which is not working. Please add as much info as possible for others.

Comment: Is there anyway to get my contact information and pictures off of my old phone and into my new phone if my old phone will not turn on or power up

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a different contact application that isn't using the normal Google android system you would have to specify the program and someone familiar with it will chime in.

Your contact information, by default is stored in Gmail's contact.  Activating your new phone and setting up the same account on the new phone as the old phone will automatically sync your contact information to your new phone.

You make a reference to sim card, where I believe you are trying to refer to an sdcard.  Many phones, especially the newer ones, will allow you connect to an external usb drive.  You can do two things to get the data off your sdcard.  You can alternatively get an adapter for your computer (which generally cost between 5 an 8 dollars), transfer the date from the card to your computer.  Then connect your new phone to your computer VIA a usb cable and transfer the data from the computer to your new phone.

Comment: L. D. James I cannot retrieve any information from my g.mail account and neither can Lookout which is a recovery app that I had installed on old phone and that I also have installed on my new. I did not have a SD card in my old phone either I was just curious about whether my information might have been stored on phones sim card but now I know that it wasn't. As my old phone will not turn on I guess that my information is not retrievable and is gone forever now

Comment: @Hogleg You don't manually retrieve information from a gmail account.  When you set up the account on your phone using the `Settings` feature to add or setup an account, the contacts and emails will be synced to the phone from the associated gmail account automatically.  The contact information that you were using on your old phone is stored on the Google server.  You would have to have a gmail account to have full access to the features of the phone, such as installing apps from `http://play.google.com`.  Add the account to your new phone and your contacts will be on it.